# Python $OUTPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR and $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR equivalent

Tags: python, file-io

Does Python have an equivalent to the $OUTPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR or $\ in Perl?

**UPDATE:**
I totally had this wrong... I was looking for a Python equivalent to a $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR if there is such a thing?
Something that you can override so that when you do a readline() type call its looking for something other than the newline char. Sorry about botching the original question.

Comment: Note to answerers: OUTPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR is what is output after a print; OUTPUT_FIELD_SEPARATOR is what is output between the arguments to print.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the ''.join method.  e.g.

```
# print 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' separated by spaces
print 'foo', 'bar', 'baz'
# print separated by commas
print ', '.join(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])
```

EDIT:

Ok, I misunderstood the purpose of `OUTPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR`, so ''.join is not what you want.

`print 'foo'` is equivalent to `sys.stdout.write('foo'+'\n')`, so you could roll your own print function:

```
def myprint(*args, end='\n'):
    sys.stdout.write(' '.join(args) + end)
```

Or go one step further with a factory function:

```
def make_printer(end):
    def myprint(*args, end='\n'):
        sys.stdout.write(' '.join(args) + end)
    return myprint

# usage:
p = make_printer('#')
p('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
```

Finally, if you're daring, you could override sys.stdout:

```
sys.old_stdout = sys.stdout
class MyWrite(object):
    def __init__(self, end='\n'):
        self.end = end
    def write(self, s):
        sys.old_stdout.write(s.replace('\n', self.end))
```

This will cause `print` statements to produce the alternative line ending.  Usage:

```
sys.stdout = MyWrite('!\n')
print 'foo'
# prints: foo!
```

Note that you may need to override more than just write() – or at least provide redirects for things like MyWrite.flush() to sys.old_stdout.flush().

Answer (score 1):

Python 3's print function has `sep` and `end` arguments.

```
print('foo', 'bar', 'baz', sep='|', end='#')
```

Note that in Python 3, `print` is no longer a statement, it is a function.

Comment: Or in the case of OUTPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR, print('foo', 'bar', 'baz', end='|')

Comment: Thanks, I edited the answer. Never did any Perl coding, so I just guessed about what OUTPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR is.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to have any of `\r`, `\n`, or `\r\n` in the input to be seen as a newline, then you can use “universal newline support” in your ‘open()’ call.

In [Python 2.6 open()](http://docs.python.org/2.6/library/functions.html#open), this needs to be explicitly enabled by adding ‘U’ to the mode string:

```
in_file = open('foo.txt', 'rU')
```

It also depends on this support being available in the Python interpreter; but the docs say this is available by default.

In [Python 3.0 open()](http://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functions.html#open), universal newline behaviour is always available, and is the default behaviour; you can choose a different behaviour with different values for the `newline` parameter.

If you want input to interpret records terminated by something other than a newline, then you don't want ‘readlines’ (which, per the name, reads lines specifically, not records generally) and AFAIK will have to implement your own record-reading code.

Comment: What if I want \x00 to be seen as the line end?

Comment: Or is there another elegant method of drinking in a little of the file at a time delimited by something other than a newline?

Comment: +1 for the Universal Newline thing. Didn't know about that. Thx.

Comment: python is normally compiled with Universal new line support enabled, so adding 'U' usually makes no different.

Comment: @SilentGhost: that's different between Python 2.6 and Python 3.0. I've updated the answer to cover this.

Answer (score 0):

In Python pre-3, you can suppress standard separator appending ',' at end of line:

```
print yourVar,  #these 3 lines print without any newline separator
print yourVar, 
print yourVar,
```

if you want to use non-standard separator, suppress normal one and print yours:

```
print yourVar, yourSep,
print yourVar, yourSep,
print yourVar, yourSep,
```

Answer (score 0):

```
open('file').read().split(your_separator_of_choice)
```

the only difference with `readlines()` here is that resulting list items won't have separator preserved at the end.